# Rental Movie from Iphone to Apple TV

Tags: itunes, icloud, appletv, television

I am wondering if my iTunes rental purchased from my iPhone is available on my Apple TV?

Comment: Any purchase made with the same Apple ID should be available on any device that is signed in with said ID. Is there a specific problem with seeing your purchase on your Apple TV?

Answer (score 1):

From Apple's site:

Can I play my rental on more than one device?

**If you download a rented movie on your computer:** You can transfer it to a device such as your Apple TV (1st generation), iPhone, iPad, or iPod if it’s a standard-definition film (movies in HD can only be watched on your computer, iPad, iPhone 4 or later, iPod touch (4th generation or later), or Apple TV). Once you move the movie from your computer to a device, the movie will disappear from your computer's iTunes library. You can move the movie between devices as many times as you wish during the rental period, but the movie can only exist on one device at a time.

**If you download a rented movie on your iPhone 4 or later, iPad, iPod touch (4th generation or later), or Apple TV:** It is not transferable to any other device or computer.

http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1657